# React - Managing UI State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

I'm creating an UI component, which should be able to maintain its own UI state, but receives data from a parent component via props. This is a common scenario, so what would be considered a best practice?

Example: A directory tree component. The component receives its structure and text content from parent component via props. However, the tree component should manage the visibility status of the nodes by itself (closed/expanded). Should I copy props to state when they are received/updated, and add visibility data there? I'm under impression that initializing state from props is a bad practice.

Comment: well, [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) is basically what you are looking for but still, you would need to handle the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

https://gist.github.com/acro5piano/4945264cfb0a83b681822332ef351ece

You do not need to copy props to local state in such case :)

If you have to modify or convert your prop data, try computed property instead:

```
get someValueFromProps() {
  return this.props.value.replace('foo', 'bar')
}
```

The less local state, the better component, as state creates bugs unless programmers pay attention to them.

Comment: Oh, it seems like my problem was that I didn't have a separate component for a node. It's much clearer when each node controls its visibility, instead of trying to control the visibility of all nodes in the tree component. Thanks for pointing that out! :)